# Overriding methods in protocols - Method does not override any method from its parent protocol

Tags: swift

I'm trying to do this:

```
protocol ProtoA: UITextViewDelegate {}
extension ProtoA {
    override func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) { print("hi") }
}
```

I get an error in reference to the method `textViewDidBeginEditing`: `Method does not override any method from its parent protocol`

The signatures appear to be exactly the same. I thought that maybe this has to do with UITextViewDelegate being `@objc` or something but other than that I'm really stumped.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need/want the `override` keyword here. Removing it should resolve the error.

`UITextViewDelegate` doesn't have its own implementation for `func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView)`, so you aren't overriding anything. Think of it as adding details to a blueprint rather than replacing an existing component with a different one.